# Object count for GCS bucket subdirectory on monitoring dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm wondering whether I can create charts for 'Object count' of a sub directory within a GCS bucket. Ideally, I'd like to use the 'Group by' option. This doesn't seem to be possible. Is there an alternative way where I could create a chart for 'Object count' for a bucket sub directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric for the object count in Google Monitoring is [defined as](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-storage):

> Total number of objects per bucket, grouped by storage class. [...]

So, if you want to create a metric that counts the number of objects in a sub-folder of a bucket you could:

List item

1. Create a [Custom Metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#creating-custom-metrics)
2. Create a [script that list and count the objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects)
3. [Write the data in the Custom Metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#writing-ts)
4. Once you do it you can create a chart with the information.

Comment: This looks like what I want. Do I understand this correctly, that I have to have some active component (eg. a VM) that generates the metric(s) and submits it? What would be the easiest (somewhat production-grade) way to get up and running with this? E.g. a single docker container?

Comment: The asey way to do that is create a [Cloud Function with the code](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python#create_a_function) and then execute it periodically with a [Cron Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#creating_jobs)

Comment: The Cloud Function has to be configured triggered by a HTTP  and the Cron Scheduler send the HTTP to trigger the fuction.